# Member can't be protected if used "fluently", even though it shouldn't be used outside

Tags: c#, .net, oop, fluent

I have the following example:

```cs
class A {
    public A DoSomethingInternal() {
        // Some work..
        return this;
    }
}

class B : A {
    public void DoSomething() {
        DoSomethingInternal().DoSomethingInternal().DoSomethingInternal();
    }
}
```

`DoSomethingInternal` is a method that should not be called by the outside objects. It should only be accessible to `A` and the inheritors of `A` - so it sounds like it should be `protected`.
However, due to the fact that `DoSomethingInternal` is a "fluent" method, I cannot make it `protected`.

A solution that I see is:

```cs
class A {
    public A DoSomethingInternal() {
        // Some work..
        return this;
    }
}

class B : A {
    public void DoSomething() {
        ((B)(((B)DoSomethingInternal()).DoSomethingInternal())).DoSomethingInternal();
    }
}
```

but I find it very inelegant to require derived classes to do these casts.

Comment: DoSomething**Internal**... shouldn't be public then I guess

Comment: @aybe That's OP's point. If `DoSomethingInternal` is `protected` in `A` and returns an `A`, then the second chained call is illegal from `B`. I would say: a fluent API is not the best idea, here.

Comment: I don't See why it should be a problem to make ```DoSomethingInternal``` a protcted member of ```A```.

Comment: @earloc Then just fire up a dotnetfiddle. Doesn't work that way.

Comment: Notice that the OP can use `protected internal` and it'll work... then we're back at same  question, why a method suffixed with `Internal` is public, it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: You seem to have the problem that ```DoSomethingInternal``` returns an ```A``` where you want it to return a ```B``` to maintain the current context and possibly further chain other calls, that might not be a member of ```A```?

Comment: @earloc https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2844

Comment: Can you please show us a practical usage of this pattern? I've been trying to develop a practical solution, but I keep coming up against not understanding the purpose of the pattern.

Comment: @Enigmativity, everywhere where _Curiously Recurring Template Pattern_ can be applied in practice ;)

Comment: Why don't you write: `public void DoSomething() {
        DoSomethingInternal(); DoSomethingInternal(); DoSomethingInternal();
    }`?

Comment: @Fabio - I quite like that pattern, but I'm still wanting to see a practical usage that the OP's looking for. The CRTP might be a perfect fit or there may be some other pattern that could apply here.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I can see that unless `DoSomethingInternal` method create a modified copy of itself it can be replaced with simple `void` method which operates on internals.

Comment: @aybe covariant-return-types might indeed help here, though derived classes would have to override ```DoSomethingInternal``` with a/the matching return-type (here ```B```) - which kind-of would look like a smell to me ;)

Comment: There is no problem to get rid of the fluent API and instead just call `this.DoSomethingInternal()`. I created this post out of pure curiosity if there is some nice way of keeping the fluent API. I also thought about the CRTP pattern - although, honestly I don't like it that much. It is one of these abstractions that are a bit "too abstract", and the code becomes unnecessarily complex. Well, I guess in my example I should just skip fluent API and everything will be fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "tell" base class about derived class as a generic type argument.

```
public abstract class A<T> where T : A<T>
{
    protected T DoSomethingInternal()
    {
        // Do something

        return (T)this;
    }
}

public class B : A<B>
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do something
        this.DoSomethingInternal().DoSomethingInternal();
    }
}
```

Comment: that´s what I would´ve suggested - even if this kind-of "tells" the base-class about details of dereived classes. But that seems an OK trade-off to me, atm.

Comment: I'm not going to apply it in practice. As I mentioned in the comment to my question, that brings unneeded complexity of inheritance chan. Curiously Recurring Template Pattern is interesting though. Marking as an Answer. Thanks